# intento hacer un bot de Telegram, con la librería telebot, tengo el inconveniente que no puedo pasar de una pregunta a otra

Tags: python-3.x, botón, telegram, telegram-bot

intento hacer un bot de Telegram, con la librería telebot, tengo el inconveniente que no puedo pasar de una pregunta a otra ya queda se queda como en un bucle en la primera pregunta y no logro pasar a la siguiente, existe un pass o break que me permita pasar a la siguiente pregunta. agradezco la ayuda. adjunto imagen de donde se presente el error. gracias a todos.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3y80Z.jpg)

```
import os
import telebot

bot= telebot.TeleBot("my token")

@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])

def start(message):
    bot.reply_to(message,"Hola, quiero darte la bienvenida.")
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,"Recuerdame tu nombre...")

@bot.message_handler(func=lambda m: True)
def nombre(message):
    nombre=message.text
    print(nombre)
    test = nombre.replace(' ','').isalpha()
    while len(nombre) < 2 or test == False:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id,"Ese no es tu nombre!, cual es tu nombre completo?...")
        return
    nombreminuscula=(nombre.lower())
    
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,"Hola, "+nombreminuscula+", es un placer verte, . ")
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,"Podría hacerte una pregunta?")

@bot.message_handler(func=lambda m: True)
def pregunta1(message):
    pregunta1=message.text
    lengpregunta1=len(pregunta1)
    while lengpregunta1 < 2:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id,"Disculpa, Podría hacerte una pregunta?")
        return
```

[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][2]][2]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: que es lo que quieres que pase?, ahí tu condición establece que la longitud del mensaje debe ser menor a 2 (ósea 0, 1 o un numero negativo) y muy pocas veces se cumplorá

Comment: eso no, el inconveniente esta en la flecha roja de la imagen no logro pasar de una pregunta a la otra.

Comment: la flecha roja apunta a la función `pregunta1()` o estoy más ciego de lo que esperaba?

Comment: si según, lo que entiendo de esta librería es allí donde se recibe el siguiente mensaje. ya que el @bot... anterior es donde se abre la opción para que el usuario escriba en telegram.